# Failed loading custom TensorFlow.js model with bundleResourceIO for React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to load a custom model into tensorflow.js in react native but am getting the error below when I try to load it.

```
Unable to resolve "../model/group1-shard1of1.bin" from "screens/CameraView.js"

undefined Unable to resolve module `../model/group1-shard1of1.bin` from `screens/CameraView.js`:
```

```
  const modelJSON = require("../model/model.json");
  const modelWeights = require("../model/group1-shard1of1.bin");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
    (async () => {
      try {
        const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
          bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights)
        );
        console.log("Model loaded");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    })();
    (async () => {
      await tf.ready();
      setTFReady(true);
    })();
    // console.log(isTFReady);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by adding a metro.config.js file with the following code to the root of the project directory

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');
module.exports = (async () => {
  const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig();
  const { assetExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;
  return {
    resolver: {
      // Add bin to assetExts
      assetExts: [...assetExts, 'bin'],
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: could you explain what this does. How did you know that the solution was related to the metro config file. I want to know for future problems. Thanks :)

Comment: @benwl, unfortunately, I do not remember how I landed on the solution as it has been quite some time since I answered it. In the future, I should be more detailed on how I landed on the answer.